# Rails restricting/changing views on user group basis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an office of 120 people, split up into groups. When they log into my app, they each need to be presented with documents related to their group, but have access to all.

I can format this info on the front end, but I'm thinking I should do this through controller vars instead.

What's the convention for this?

Should I set the `@documents` by saying `@documents = Documents.where(group: user.group)`, or filter that out by JS on the front end?

Please advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better to make queering on server side. It's beneficial for two important reasons.

The first one is efficiency. If there are many documents, sending them to each customer will be problematic.

The seconds reason is security. If you require different groups have different access level to documents you should not be sending all documents to all clients.

I also think this way you will get more scalability.

Comment: Good info. What's a good way to set this up? Just set my @doc with a where clause?

Comment: @KevinBrown yes, filtering groups like you've shown in your question is a good idea.

Comment: if I have a bunch of named scopes, is there a good way to apply that filter/scope to all of the ones preceding? Or should I just chain and refactor a bit....all my code so far puts everyone in one group.